# Callback function behaviour in JS

Tags: javascript

I came across callback functions in JS and found it to be really amazing. Though there is something about how callbacks behave that i am not able to understand.
Example:

```
function add(num1, num2){
  return num1 + num2;
}

function displaySum(num1, num2, callback){
  let a = callback(num1, num2)
  console.log(a);
}

setTimeout(displaySum(3,5,add), 3000); // This displays the result instantly
```

And in a similar case

```js
function displayText(text){
    console.log('HEY JS');
}
setTimeout(displayText, 3000) //This seems to work
```

I am not able to understand why is this happening?

Comment: `setTimeout()` expects a function as its first argument. You are passing it the return value of `displaySum()` (which is `undefined`) as you are calling `displaySum` rather than letting `setTimeout` call it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are directly calling the function inside the `setTimeout`. That function gets invoked and nothing is sent back.

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#parameters) expects a function to be executed after the timer expires. You should only specify the referene to that function.

```
setTimeout(displaySum(3,5,add), 3000);
```

With the above statement you are instantly calling the `displaySum` function with 3 parameters. That is why you can see the result instantly. This function donot have a return value so there is no event that needs to be triggered after specified interval.

Replace that with

```
setTimeout(() => displaySum(3, 5, add), 3000);
```

Here the arraw function returns `displaySum(3, 5, add)`, and this function will be called after specified interval.

```js
function add(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

function displaySum(num1, num2, callback) {
    let a = callback(num1, num2)
    console.log(a);
}

setTimeout(() => displaySum(3, 5, add), 3000);
```